# laravel 9 bug when writing

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have 3 small problems in my code

Livewire ThreadDisplay.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Thread;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\ThreadReply;
use Auth;

class ThreadDisplay extends Component
{   
    public Thread $thread;
    public ThreadReply $threadreply;
    public $description;
    
    protected $listeners = ['update-thread' => 'updatethread'];

    public function mount(Thread $thread)
    {
        $this->thread = $thread;
        // dd($this->thread);
    }

    public function react($reaction)
    {
        if ($this->thread->isLiked()) {
            $this->thread->toggleReaction($reaction);
            if($reaction == $this->thread->reacted()?->type){
                if($reaction == 'hand-thumbs-down-fill' || $reaction == 'emoji-frown-fill' ){
                    $user = User::find($this->thread->user->id)->increment('reactions', 1);
                }else{
                    $user = User::find($this->thread->user->id)->decrement('reactions', 1);
                }
            }else{
                $negative = ['hand-thumbs-down-fill','emoji-frown-fill'];
                $positive = ['hand-thumbs-up-fill','emoji-heart-eyes-fill','heart-fil'];
                if(in_array($reaction,$negative)){
                    if(!in_array($this->thread->reacted()->type,$negative)){
                        $user = User::find($this->thread->user->id)->decrement('reactions', 2);
                    }
                }else{
                    if(!in_array($this->thread->reacted()->type,$positive)){
                        $user = User::find($this->thread->user->id)->increment('reactions', 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else{
            $this->thread->toggleReaction($reaction);
            if($reaction == 'hand-thumbs-down-fill' || $reaction == 'emoji-frown-fill' ){
                $user = User::find($this->thread->user->id)->decrement('reactions', 1);
            }else{
                $user = User::find($this->thread->user->id)->increment('reactions', 1);
            }
        }
        $this->thread = Thread::find($this->thread->id);
    }
    
    public function replysubmit(){
        $threadreply = new ThreadReply();
        $threadreply->thread_id = $this->thread->id;
        $threadreply->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $threadreply->description = $this->description;
        $this->description = '';
        $threadreply->save();
        $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('threadreplysent');
    }

    public function updatethread(){
        $this->thread = Thread::find($this->thread->id);
    }


    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.thread-display');
    }
}
```

Livewire ThreadReply.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\ThreadReply as TR;
use App\Models\Thread;
use App\Models\User;
use Auth;

class ThreadReply extends Component
{
    public TR $reply;
    public function mount(TR $reply)
    {
        $this->reply = $reply;
    }

    public function react($reaction)
    {
        if ($this->reply->isLiked()) {
            $this->reply->toggleReaction($reaction);
            if($reaction == $this->reply->reacted()?->type){
                if($reaction == 'hand-thumbs-down-fill' || $reaction == 'emoji-frown-fill' ){
                    $user = User::find($this->reply->user->id)->increment('reactions', 1);
                }else{
                    $user = User::find($this->reply->user->id)->decrement('reactions', 1);
                }
            }else{
                $negative = ['hand-thumbs-down-fill','emoji-frown-fill'];
                $positive = ['hand-thumbs-up-fill','emoji-heart-eyes-fill','heart-fil'];
                if(in_array($reaction,$negative)){
                    if(!in_array($this->reply->reacted()->type,$negative)){
                        $user = User::find($this->reply->user->id)->decrement('reactions', 2);
                    }
                }else{
                    if(!in_array($this->reply->reacted()->type,$positive)){
                        $user = User::find($this->reply->user->id)->increment('reactions', 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else{
            $this->reply->toggleReaction($reaction);
            if($reaction == 'hand-thumbs-down-fill' || $reaction == 'emoji-frown-fill' ){
                $user = User::find($this->reply->user->id)->decrement('reactions', 1);
            }else{
                $user = User::find($this->reply->user->id)->increment('reactions', 1);
            }
        }
        $this->reply = TR::find($this->reply->id);
        $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('replyreaction');
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.thread-reply');
    }
}
```

ThreadController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\User;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use App\Models\Thread;
use App\Models\ThreadReply;
use App\Models\SubCategory;
use Auth;

class ThreadController extends Controller
{
    public function create($subcategory){
        return view('threads.create',compact('subcategory'));
    }

    public function store(Request $request,$subcategory){
        $category = SubCategory::where('title',$subcategory)->first();
        $thread = new Thread();
        $thread->title = $request->title;
        $thread->slug = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', str_replace(' ', '-', $request->title)).'-'.Str::random(5);
        $thread->description = $request->description;
        $thread->sub_category_id = $category->id;
        $thread->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $thread->save();
        return redirect()->route('subcategory.thread',$request->subcategory);
    }

    public function show($slug){
        $thread = Thread::where('slug',$slug)->first();
        return view('threads.show',compact('thread'));
    }

}
```

create thread

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('stylesheets')
    {{-- <link href="{{ asset('ckeditor/contents.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"> --}}
@endsection
@section('content')
    <div class="container-fluid mt-5">
        <form action="{{ route('thread.store',$subcategory) }}" method="POST">
            @csrf
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-12 m-auto">
                    <div class="card shadow">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <h4 class="card-title"> Post Thread </h4>
                        </div>

                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label> Title </label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" placeholder="Enter the Title" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group" >
                                <label> Description </label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="description" placeholder="Enter the Description" name="description"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"> Save </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
@endsection
@section('scripts')
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.19.0/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script>
    // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with a CKEditor 4
    // instance, using default configuration.
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'description' );
</script>
@endsection
```

The first bug I have; when I try to write in reply thread, it takes me to the top of the page and I have to click back to continue writing.

My other problem is when I create a thread and the description is empty I get this error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'description' cannot be null

I would like that instead of the error that you see, I would like it to write to provide me with an error description.

Comment: *when I try to write in reply thread, it takes me to the top of the page and I have to click back to continue writing* - Not sure what you mean by this? For your other problem, use [validation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation), specifically the [`required`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-required) rule.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing standard HTML forms with Livewire. If you're going to use Livewire, use it for everything. When you submit your form it's "jumping" to the top of the page because its not respecting the Livewire component, it's just treating it like a static page.

For your form, use `wire:submit.prevent="myAction"` and then add `myAction` function to your Livewire component. Stop mixing static, oldschool forms when you can use the superior Livewire equivalent.

Comment: thanks for your answer but i have don't understand what i need to change, i'm begginer i try to do project for school for learn. how can i resolve this problem?

Comment: Read the livewire docs, for example: https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/input-validation

Comment: I have check but i have don't understand what i need to change for it's not go in top when i reply in thread?

Answer (score 0):

The SqlState error cannot be null  come because you didnt put description column as nullable like this

```
$this->text('description')->nullable();
```

and like this you can send empty value of descrption without probleme

Comment: Actually, it might be intentional that it's not nullable. So instead, I suggest that you add validation before submitting the form.